# Example of a concave function with $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{g(x)}{-x\ln x}=\infty$ which fullfills some additional condition

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, convex-analysis

I'm looking for the example of a concave function $g \colon [0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, with $g(0)=0$, for which

1. $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\frac{g(x)}{-x\ln x}=\infty$, and
2. $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\lambda g(x)}{g(\lambda x)}=1$ for every $\lambda>1$

Answer (score 2):

Take $g_1(x)=x\log^2x$. Properties 1,2 are evidently satisfied, and computation
of the second derivative shows that it is negative for $0< x<1/e$.
Now rescale: $g(x)=g_1(x/e)$.